# Going wrong in obtaining cert object

Tags: java, security, spring-security, certificate, x509

```
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TrustManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void testTrust() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("done 0");
        Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resources/certificate.cer"));
        System.out.println("done 1");
    }
}
```

I have checked the contents of the certificate.cer file and it does contain the certificate.
I am getting the below exception, while creating the cert object. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Missing input stream
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.manh.msf.rest.auth.TrustManagerTest.testTrust(TrustManagerTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
```

Comment: I would pull out the `getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resources/certificate.cer")` part and see what that returns. At a guess you are missing a leading /.

Comment: How about an absolute path , which throws the same exception. Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(getClass().getResourc‌​eAsStream("C:\\Resources\\certificate.cer"));

Comment: InputStream c = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resources/certificate.cer");                            c is having null value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
getResourceAsStream("Resources/certificate.cer")
```

If the parent directory of `/Resources` is not in your `CLASSPATH`, then `getResourceAsStream` will return `null`.

This works well for me:

```
public class ClassLoaderDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoaderDemo.class.getClassLoader();
            if (classLoader != null) {
                InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("mesh.xml");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My input file was not in the package; I had it in a /resources directory that I added to my CLASSPATH.

Comment: How about an absolute path , which throws the same exception.      Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Resources\\certificate.cer"));

Comment: Did you try the CLASSPATH relative path yet?

Comment: If it's a file in the file system, use FileInputStream, not getResourceAsStream.

Comment: Actually he is calling Class.getResourceAsStream(), so Resources would need to be in the package of the class concerned.